# web.config to mod_rewrite returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis, web-config

First time using mod_rewrite here I have this rules working on IIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="services" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([a-z]+)/service/([a-zA-Z-]+)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="serveis.php?id={R:2}&amp;lang={R:1}"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="categories" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([a-z]+)/category/([a-zA-Z-]+)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="subhome.php?id={R:2}&amp;lang={R:1}"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="index_idioma" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([a-z]+)/index" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?lang={R:1}"/>
                </rule>
                 <rule name="index" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="http://www.domain.com" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.domain.com/index.php?lang=en"/>
                </rule>
                  <rule name="kinds" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([a-z]+)/kind" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="tipusserveis.php?lang={R:1}"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="company" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([a-z]+)/our_company" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/empresa.php?lang={R:1}" />
                </rule>
                 <rule name="contact" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([a-z]+)/contact" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/contacto.php?lang={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And now I want to make it using apache's mod_rewrite I tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+) index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/our_company/?$ empresa.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/contact/?$ contacto.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/service/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ serveis.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ subhome.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/kind/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ tipusserveis.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

but none of them is working.

Can somebody help me here, atleast give me some directions on how I should do it?

EDIT:
Plesk Panel automatically adds this to `httpd.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 [L,R=301]
<IfModule>
```

I guess it removes the www from the URL but I don't know if it also stops the other rules to be applied. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are getting errors in `mod_rewrite` due to missing anchors `^` and `$` in your URI patterns. Try these rules in your root `.htaccess` or in Apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/our_company/?$ empresa.php?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/contact/?$ contacto.php?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/service/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ serveis.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/category/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ subhome.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/kind/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ tipusserveis.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: These rules aren't working either, I'm still getting `400 Bad Request` or `404 Not Found`

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Are there more rules in your .htaccess or these are the only rules? Also tell me for which URL did you 400 and 404?

Comment: I'm using Parallels Plesk Panel and I dont know why .htaccess file is ignored so I'm writing the rules in the apache config file.

Comment: All of them are returning 400, there was one returning 404 but I was missing a rewrite rule.

Comment: For testing purpose create a .htaccess in your `DocumentRoot` and place these rules there. Otherwise Apache needs to be restarted every time you make a change in rules.

Comment: First let me clarify that `Still not working` type of comments are not going to help you. What URL did you try? Where is this .htaccess located now? Did you check Apache error.log when you got 400? Does 400 go away when you remove this .htaccess?

Comment: I've tried all rewrite rules, I'm still getting `400`, `.htaccess` is located at the `DocumentRoot`, Apache erroe log doesn't show anything about this errors and when I remove the `.htaccess` Im just getting the 404s

Comment: Comment all rule except very first one and retry. You still **didn't tell me which URL you used for testing**

Comment: I've tried `http://domain.com/en` with all rules commented but the first one, still getting 400 and nothing on the error.log

Comment: Still the same, returning 400 and no errors in the log, when I access the URL directly `domain.com/index.php?lang=en` it works

Comment: I just noticed that there is a hardcoded rule in `httpd.conf` that maight be the cause, I'm updating the question with the new info

Comment: ok can you comment out that rule in `httpd.conf` and retest? If you need to remove `www` I will provide you a better rule to be kept in `.htaccess`.

Comment: I can't the file is autogenerated when I restart apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57845/discussion-between-anubhava-and-gbestard).

Answer (score 1):

1) Your subsittution (2nd parameter) must not be a relative path. It needs to either start with a / or be a redirect, never just e.g. "index.php".  This is the direct cause of your 400s -- your error log probably clearly showed a URL-path not starting with / (which is invalid)

2) You should ignore the suggestions to put these rules in .htaccess.  This makes mod_rewrite much more complex to maintain.